# Visual Studio Run specific source C++ File

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to know how to run a specific files in source files in my project.  For example, I have 2 files in my source file, Exer1, Exer2. Now, the Exer1 file is already selected as the default startup file. I want to run the Exer2, however I don't know how to do it.  Or much better I could run a selected file.  Is this possible? Or do I need to create a new project?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `main()` function in each of them? Then you'l need different projects for each.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @isanae, well I don't really care about the damn downvotes.  Whats the most important thing to me is that my questions are answered.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "run a source file". Source files are compiled and linked together to make an executable. In Visual Studio, this is what a *project* does. Building a project will give you an executable that will run when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Now, you can have multiple projects in a *solution* and they can all generate a different executable. Which one gets started when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> depends on the current *StartUp* project. To change it, you can right-click on a project and select "Set as StartUp Project".

[image: screenshot of the context menu with "Set as StartUp Project" highlighted]